# Loading GPX files from AmazonS3 with Google-Maps-APIv3 only works locally, but not on a deployed site (Heroku)

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, google-maps-api-3, gpx

I'm trying to apply Google Maps API (v3) on my site, which is deployed on Heroku.
The map is populated with a given GPX file, provided by JS/Ajax.
The GPX file is stored on AmazonS3.

( I don't think that it's matter, but note the the site is built with Django, and the GPX file is a FileField of the relevant model ).

It works very well locally (local ip), but the map is not loaded at the deployed site.
I couldn't track any related error on the server logs, e.g. wrong key, etc.

Following is the relevant code snippet:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 50%; height: 50%;"></div>

<script>
    function loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap(map, filename) {
        $.ajax({url: filename,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(data) {
                    var parser = new GPXParser(data, map);
                    parser.setTrackColour("#ff0000");     // Set the track line colour
                    parser.setTrackWidth(5);              // Set the track line width
                    parser.setMinTrackPointDelta(0.001);  // Set the minimum distance between track points
                    parser.centerAndZoom(data);
                    parser.addTrackpointsToMap();         // Add the trackpoints
                    parser.addRoutepointsToMap();         // Add the routepoints
                    parser.addWaypointsToMap();           // Add the waypoints
                }
        });
    }

    function initMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap(map, "{{ object.gpx_file.url }}");
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Here is the corresponding snapshots:

[image]

Following is the console log (Chrome), while on the deployed site:

[image]

Can you please assist me with that?
Is that a GoogleMaps API issue? an AmazonS3 issue? Other?
How can I make GoogleMaps work on the deployed site?

Thanks ahead,
Shahar

Comment: If possible provide a link to the source code and a link to the deployed site. Definitely do add any errors in the browser client and potential differences in log output.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a bit hard, since the site is confidential, and I cannot share this data. I don't see any errors in the logs. Can you please try helping me out without accessing the site itself?

Comment: I think this error is not Heroku related. Try deploying your website on a VPS and access it remotely via an ip address. It probably will not work. On localhost it will work because google has less restriction on local development environments. It's something with the API key.

Comment: I've just added the console log (Chrome), from the deployed site

Comment: The error seems to be a consecutive error from Google Maps not showing up. `loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap`. Have you tried deploying your website on a VPS and accessing it via its internet IP address?

Comment: Issue has been resolved, thanks for your support.

I just had a chat with Google support, and understood it's an AmazonS3 issue and/or Ajax issue.
They showed me that Google API returns a valid response (200), while AmazonS3 returns a ForbiddenAccess response (400).
I looked at that direction, and ended-up with changing the above code as following:

OLD (broken):
loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap(map, "{{ object.gpx_file.url }}");

NEW (works):
loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap(map, "{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ object.training_map }}");